# Looking for a mystery novel in a mountain with a serial killer

Tags: identification-request

I am trying to remember a book. The story happens in a mountain, if I remember correctly it takes place in a mountain refuge when the main character investigates about the death of other people of the refuge, and at the end he remembers he is the killer, he killed them in a psychiatric crisis.

Do you have an idea about the novel's name?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Please read the [wiki for identification requests](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and provide additional information that could help us narrow down the search. E.g., when and where did you read the book? Was it a new book when you read it, or one published earlier? In what time period is it set? What do you remember about the physical book—cover, length, etc.? Please [edit the question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/25848/edit) to provide these details, don't put them in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Francis Beeding, *[The House of Dr Edwardes](https://freeread.com.au/@RGLibrary/FrancisBeeding/Novels/TheHouseOfDoctorEdwardes.html)* (1928)? Stephen King, *[The Shining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shining_(novel))* (1977)? Agatha Christie, *[The Mousetrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mousetrap)* (1952)?

Comment: Thank you @verbose but it is not one of those book. I read the book like 15 years ago. I don't remember any other information.